# How to add a prop to components inside an array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-props

I have an array with a bunch of React components without a `key` prop.

I'd like to loop over them and add it.

How can I do it?

Example:

```
const elements = [<Component someProp={someValue}/>, <Component someProp={someValue}/>];

elements.forEach((item,index) => {
  // HOW CAN I ADD key TO THE COMPONENTS HERE ?
});
```

PS: Yes, I can do it when I'm creating the array, but I chose not to, in order to improve readability.

Is it possible?

Comment: You will find many similar questions by searching "How to add props to an existing component", having them in an array is deciding how to aggregate it after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const elements = [<Component someProp={someValue}/>, <Component someProp={someValue}/>];

elements.map((item,index) => {
  return React.cloneElement(item, {
     someNewProp
  }
});
```

this Key is React.cloneElement